# JQuery button OnClick not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

Hope everybody is having a good day. I had this buton and code, which worked for me.
I also followed the jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/click/

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnName").click(function () {
            console.log("test");
        });

}
```

I then upgraded webpack and JQuery

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If anybody can help me out that would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Edit: HTML for button:

```
  <!-- NEW CONTACT BUTTON -->
                <div class="new-contact-buttons">
                    <div class="btn-grouped">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block bottom" id="btnRetrieveCallerMatches" disabled style="display:none;">Retrieve 
                            caller matches</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block bottom" id="btnNewContactForm" disabled style="display:none;">New
                            contact</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am now trying this code, but unfortunately its still not working:

```
$(function () {


   $("#btnNewContactForm").click(function () {
     console.log("@@@@@@@@ clicked new contact")
     });

});
```

I re-enable the button when I need it using:

```
    $("#btnNewContactForm").show();
    $("#btnNewContactForm").removeAttr("disabled");
```

And the button shows up so that piece of code works.

I also checked if the top function is being executed and it is.

Comment: Please include the HTML for the button.   `#btnName.app` would only work if it has id=btnName *and* class=app.   `$("#btnName").on("click", "#btnName"` will only work if you have a nested button inside the button, with the same id (unlikely...).  Your original code should still have worked.

Comment: Which version of jquery did you upgrade *from*?  Did you try a newer version?  eg 3.6.0

Comment: Note: `$(function () {` and `$(document).ready(function() {` are different syntaxes for the same thing.  You only need one or the other (use `$(function() {`.  There's no issue nesting them as the doc.ready will still fire even if document was ready before the code ran, but there's no need for them.

Comment: Oh and I also updated my JQuery to 3.6.0, thanks for the advice. Unfortunately it didnt do anything for the button.

Comment: `style="display:none;"` your button is not visible?

Comment: Do you have multiple buttons for "new contact"?   ie multiple buttons with the same ID?  `$("#id")` will only pick up the first one as IDs should be unique in the html.

Comment: Yeah sorry I mentioned it in the post, I  re-enable the button when I need it a bit of code, I also attached that in the OP now. I don't think it has anything to do with why it is not working because I can see the button when I need to see it.

Comment: Oh, and I also checked if the top $(function () { } ); is being run with a console.log and the function runs fine.

Comment: Add a `console.log($("#btnNewContactForm").length)` to determine if the element exists when your code runs (it should unless you build it later, which you don't mention and your original code would also not have worked)

Comment: The length from the console log is 1! I can also see the button, doesn't that mean the element exists? Thanks again for all the help by the way.

Comment: Yes, please also, try `console.log($("[id=btnNewContactForm]").length)`  should also be 1.

Comment: console.log($("[id=btnNewContactForm]").length) is also 1!

Comment: What if you put your webpack / jquery back to what it was?  Does it then start working?  There's nothing obvious in the js and you've confirmed jquery is at least loading.

Comment: Managed to get it working by using a workaround, I check for the mouseup function and then check the event, if the event.target.id == btnNewContactForm I call another function. But I don't think this is intended/best practice/efficient.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue here in a snippet?  Seems like there's something specific to your page as the code *as provided* works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/2wpgd41r/

Comment: I answered the SO question. A tablesorter method couldn't be found because of the upgrades, and any code after that wasn't being executed. Thanks for all your help and I hope I didn't waste too much of your time.

Answer (score 0):

Just before the button code I had a sort method:

```
$(".phonebook table").tablesorter();
```

I think because the upgrade (webpack or jquery) this function stopped working  and it wouldn't execute any code after this. So the code was fine all along but the binding code wasn't executing. Sorry for wasting everyones time.

When I put this code before the tablesorter everyting worked fine:

```
    $("#btnNewContactForm").click(function () {
        console.log("@@@@@@@" + "saving new contact");
        newContact();
    });
```

Comment: So instead of answering your own question, you can delete the question

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="btnName">click me</button>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#btnName").on("click", function () {
        console.log("test");
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

In each and every one of your examples you are forgetting to close your function, small syntax mistake, but the following code will work

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#btnName").click(function () {
               console.log("test");
           });
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnName">Hi</button>
```

Comment: `$(function () {` AND  `$(document).ready(function() {` are identical and do not both need to be there. `$(function () { /code here */ });` is enough

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', "#btnName.app", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("clicked");
  });
});
```

you forgot to put ")" in the end of `$(function(){...})`

Comment: I'm sorry I accidentally edited your answer instead of mine!